# How to obtain the identity $\sum_k\frac{(m-k)!}{(n-k)!} = \frac{(m+1-k)!}{(m+1-n)(n-k)!}$

Tags: combinatorics, factorial

Hereby $$\sum_k\frac{(m-k)!}{(n-k)!} = \frac{(m+1-k)!}{(m+1-n)(n-k)!} =: SOL(k)$$
is supposed to be similar to the way of writing antiderivatives. In complete form it should be like this:
$$\sum_{k=a}^b \frac{(m-k)!}{(n-k)!} = SOL(b)-SOL(a)$$

I'm not completely sure whether it actually holds for all $a,b$.

Okay, using Pascal's identity, I get:
$$\sum_{k=a}^b \binom{m-k}{m-n}=\\
\binom{m-a}{m-n}+\sum_{k=a+1}^b \binom{m-k}{m-n}\\
= \binom{m-a-1}{m-n} +\binom{m-a-1}{m-n-1}+\sum_{k=a+1}^b \binom{m-k}{m-n} \\
= \binom{m-a-1}{m-n} +\binom{m-a-1}{m-n-1}+\binom{m-a-1}{m-n}+\sum_{k=a+2}^b \binom{m-k}{m-n}\\
= \binom{m-a-1}{m-n-1}+2\binom{m-a-1}{m-n}+ \sum_{k=a+2}^b \binom{m-k}{m-n}\\
= \binom{m-a-1}{m-n-1}+2\binom{m-a-2}{m-n}+2\binom{m-a-2}{m-n-1} \sum_{k=a+2}^b \binom{m-k}{m-n}\\
=(\sum_{i=a+1}^{b-1} i\binom{m-a-i}{m-n-1}) + b\binom{m-b}{m-n}
$$

Comment: Note that left side is $\sum_{k=a}^b (m-n)!\cdot\binom{m-k}{m-n}$ and use Pascal's identity

Comment: @Jakobian But in Pascal's identity, the lower entry of the binomial runs. If I use the identity to apply it onto this... it looks a lot more complex

Comment: I believe Jakobian was referring to the Hockey Stick identity.

Comment: @MikeEarnest Oh, that would make sense. After all, this is a slight derivation of my previous question, which was the Hockey Stick identity. But I fear my brain is just burned out right now, I can't seem to get anywhere

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks that your question is relevant to the [Indefinite Sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indefinite_sum) concept.

If we have that
$$
\Delta _{\,x} \,F(x) = F(x + 1) - F(x) = f(x)
$$
then we write 
$$
F(x) = \Delta _{\,x} ^{\, - \,1} \,f(x) = \sum\nolimits_{\;x\;} {f(x)} 
$$
in particular we have
$$
F(b) - F(a) = \sum\nolimits_{\;x = \,a\,}^b {f(x)}  =  - \sum\nolimits_{\;x = \,b\,}^a {f(x)} 
$$

The relation with the standard definition of the sum of a function of discrete variable is 
$$
\sum\limits_{k = a}^{b - 1} {f(k)}  = \sum\limits_{a\, \le \,k\, < \,b} {f(k)}  = \sum\nolimits_{\;k = \,a\,}^b {f(k)}
   = F(b) - F(a)\quad \left| \matrix{ \;a,b \in \mathbb Z \hfill \cr 
  \;a \le b \hfill \cr}  \right.
$$

The first two sum are "standard", the third is meant to indicate the Indef. one.
Note the $< $ in the second ! that is exactly what is needed to allow the chain
    $\sum\limits_{a\, \le \,k\, < \,b}+\sum\limits_{b\, \le \,k\, < \,c}=\sum\limits_{a\, \le \,k\, < \,c}$ with $\sum\limits_{a\, \le \,k\, < \,a}=0$

corresponding to
$\sum\nolimits_{\;k = \,a\,}^{\;b} +\sum\nolimits_{\;k = \,b\,}^{\;c}=\sum\nolimits_{\;k = \,a\,}^{\;c} \quad;\quad \sum\nolimits_{\;k = \,a\,}^{\;b}+ \sum\nolimits_{\;k = \,b\,}^{\;a}=0\quad \to \quad \sum\nolimits_{\;k = \,a\,}^{\;b} = - \sum\nolimits_{\;k = \,b\,}^{\;a}$

That premised, for the binomials we have
$$
\Delta _{\,x} \,\left( \matrix{
  x \cr 
  q \cr}  \right) = \left( \matrix{
  x + 1 \cr 
  q \cr}  \right) - \left( \matrix{
  x \cr 
  q \cr}  \right) = \left( \matrix{
  x \cr 
  q - 1 \cr}  \right)\quad  \Rightarrow \quad \sum\nolimits_{\;x\;} {\left( \matrix{
  x \cr 
  q \cr}  \right)}  = \left( \matrix{
  x \cr 
  q + 1 \cr}  \right)
$$
and therefore
$$
\eqalign{
  & \Delta _{\,x} \,\left( \matrix{
  r - x \cr 
  q \cr}  \right) = \left( \matrix{
  r - x - 1 \cr 
  q \cr}  \right) - \left( \matrix{
  r - x \cr 
  q \cr}  \right) =  - \left( \matrix{
  r - x - 1 \cr 
  q - 1 \cr}  \right) = \left( { - 1} \right)^q \left( \matrix{
  q - r + x - 1 \cr 
  q - 1 \cr}  \right)  \cr 
  & \sum\nolimits_{\;x\;} {\left( \matrix{
  r - x \cr 
  q \cr}  \right)}  =  - \left( \matrix{
  r - x + 1 \cr 
  q + 1 \cr}  \right)  \cr 
  & \sum\limits_{k = 0}^b {\left( \matrix{
  r - k \cr 
  q \cr}  \right)}  =  - \left( \matrix{
  r - \left( {b - 1} \right) + 1 \cr 
  q + 1 \cr}  \right) + \left( \matrix{
  r - 0 + 1 \cr 
  q + 1 \cr}  \right) \cr} 
$$
which applies also to complex values of $r,q,b$ if the binomial is defined through the Gamma  function.

From here you should be able to conclude for your particular case.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! A few questions: 1) In the 5th line do you mean $F(x) = \Delta _{\,x} ^{\, - \,1} \,f(x) = \sum\nolimits_{\;x\;} {f(x)}$; In the third formula, why does the sum run in the third case to $b$?

Comment: Thanks for the elaborate explanation! This piece of understanding came a lot harder to me than it should have...

Comment: @Sudix:  a) you are right sorry, amended b) don't get your point: bounds of Indef. Sum can be inverted (unlike normal one)  and made piecewise, similar to integral. c) Indef. Sum requires some stressing on the acquired summing knowkedge, but its manageability is worth the effort.

Comment: b) Ah, my bad, cited the wrong formula. $$\sum\limits_{k = a}^{b - 1} {f(k)}  = \sum\limits_{a\, \le \,k\, < \,b} {f(k)}  = \sum\nolimits_{\;k = \,a\,}^b {f(k)}
   = F(b) - F(a)\quad \left| \matrix{ \;a,b \in \mathbb Z \hfill \cr 
  \;a \le b \hfill \cr}  \right.$$ Here, shouldn't it be $\sum_{k=a}^{b-1}$ (the third part);  c) True that. I already like the concept - the similarity to integrals, that it gives us a concrete inverse operation. If you know any introductions/books to it, I'd be happy!

Comment: @Sudix b) that's a key-point lower limit is included upper is excluded, i.e. $k \in [a,b)$, actually that is the proper formulation also for integral. I added a note in the answer. c) A very exhaustive, magnifically explained, introduction to Summation (and many others) with examples & exercises is given in the renowned "Concrete  Mathematics"

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
&\bbox[10px,#ffd]{\sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}{\pars{m - k}! \over \pars{m - n}!}} =
\pars{m - n}!\sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}{m - k \choose  m - n}
\\[5mm] = &\
\pars{m - n}!\sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}\bracks{z^{m - n}}
\pars{1 + z}^{m - k} =
\pars{m - n}!\bracks{z^{m - n}}\pars{1 + z}^{m}\sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}
\pars{1 \over 1 + z}^{k}
\\[5mm] = &\
\pars{m - n}!\bracks{z^{m - n}}\pars{1 + z}^{m}\,
{1 \over 1 - 1/\pars{1 + z}} =
\pars{m - n}!\bracks{z^{m - n + 1}}\pars{1 + z}^{m + 1}
\\[5mm] = &\
\bbx{\pars{m - n}!{m + 1 \choose m - n + 1}}
\end{align}

Comment: An interesting approach. So, this idea would be representation $$\sum_{k=a}^b a_n = \sum_{k=a}^\infty a_n -\sum_{k=b}^\infty a_n =$$ There's one equality though that I don't get: $$ \sum_{k=0}^\infty \binom{m-k}{m-n} =\sum_{k=0}^\infty [z^{m-n}] (1+z)^{m-k}$$

Comment: @Sudix: The *coefficient of* operator $[z^k]$ denotes the coefficient of $z^k$ in a series. This way we can write for instance $[z^k](1+z)^n=\binom{n}{k}$.